# Implementar Interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, interface

Tenho a classe abstrata `ClasseA` e 2 classes filhas `ClasseB` e `ClasseC`, depois tenho uma interface `IClasse` que é implementada em `ClasseA` e `ClasseB`.

Na interface tenho o método `metodo1` que recebe uma instância da `ClasseA`, mas nas implementações desse método nas classes filhas de `ClasseA` eu preciso que o `metodo1` receba uma instância da sua respectiva classe, por exemplo na implementação em `ClasseB` o método deve receber uma instância `ClasseB`, na implementação em `ClasseC` ele deve receber uma instância `ClasseC`.

Não sei ao certo mas isso não devia funcionar por serem classes filhas de ClasseA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que é isto que você deseja. O exemplo é meio esdrúxulo mas funciona (eu teria feito em cima do que você já produziu se tivesse postado o código):

```
using System.Console;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var cA = new ClasseA();
        var cB = new ClasseB();
        cA.Metodo1(cA);
        cB.Metodo1(cB);
    }
}

public interface IClasse<T> where T : IClasse<T> {
    void Metodo1(T parametro);
}

public class ClasseA : IClasse<ClasseA> {
    public void Metodo1(ClasseA parametro) {
        WriteLine("ClasseA");
        return;
    }
}

public class ClasseB : IClasse<ClasseB> {
    public void Metodo1(ClasseB parametro) {
        WriteLine("ClasseB");
        return;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/M66JVW). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JK63XN). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Generics/InterfaceImplementation.cs).

O segredo é usar um tipo genérico na interface e especializá-lo na classe. Note que é possível restringir que a classe só pode implementar a interface com outra `IClasse`. Mas não dá para garantir que seja a própria classe que está sendo implementada.

Se isto for realmente necessário durante o desenvolvimento pode-se criar um *plugin* para o Visual Studio com o [.NET Compiler Platform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compiler_Platform) para identificar e restringir o uso de outra classe. Mas só vai restringir se o programador tiver o *plugin* instalado e ativo. Além disto é pouco provável que valha o esforço.

Comment: Cara funcionou certinho, eu já tinha lido algo sobre essa técnica mas não tinha intendido direito por que o material não era tão claro, e agora que eu implementei isso em uma necessidade fica mais fácil de intender o funcionamento. Quanto a garantir a implementação da própria classe pelo menos por enquanto não é problema, muito obrigado.