# Alternativa ao uso de new ao implementar métodos que retornam this em classes filhas

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos

Tendo como exemplo o seguinte código:

```
public class Pai
{
    protected string PropriedadeA { get; set; }
    public Pai Metodo1(int valor)
    {
        //Vários procedimentos feitos aqui
        PropriedadeA = "Resultado do tratamento";
        return this;
    }
}

public class Filha : Pai
{
    public new Filha Metodo1(int valor)
    {
        base.Metodo1(valor);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Existe alguma alternativa que evite rescrever o método na classe `Filha`?

Isto surgiu da necessidade de implementar a característica de *Fluent Interface* em várias classes. Essas classes vão herdando as funcionalidades das outras e acrescentam novas.

Para que a *Fluent Interface* funcione os métodos têm de retornar a classe `Filha` e não a classe `Pai`.

```
public interface IDataConfiguration<TResponse>
{
    TResponse GetData();
    Task<TResponse> GetDataAsync();
}

public interface IDataVideoConfiguration<TResponse> : IDataConfiguration<TResponse>
{
    IDataVideoConfiguration<TResponse> VideoName(string videoName);
    IDataVideoConfiguration<TResponse> CosmoId(string cosmoId);
    IDataVideoConfiguration<TResponse> I_GuideId(string iGuideId);
}

public interface IDataVideoImagesConfiguration<TResponse>
{
    IDataVideoImagesConfiguration<TResponse> VideoName(string videoName);
    IDataVideoImagesConfiguration<TResponse> CosmoId(string cosmoId);
    IDataVideoImagesConfiguration<TResponse> I_GuideId(string iGuideId);

    IDataVideoImagesConfiguration<TResponse> ImageFormatId(string formatId);
    IDataVideoImagesConfiguration<TResponse> ImageSize(string imageSize);
    IDataVideoImagesConfiguration<TResponse> ImageSort(string imageSort);
    TResponse GetData(int count = 0, int offset = 0);
    Task<TResponse> GetDataAsync(int count = 0, int offset = 0);
}
```

A classe `Pai` implementa `IDataVideoConfiguration<TResponse>` o problema surge ao implementar a classe `Filha` herdando de `Pai`:

```
public class Filha<TResponse> : Pai<TResponse>, IDataVideoImagesConfiguration<TResponse>
```

Comment: Não sei se entendi o que você deseja efetivamente. Na forma que está simplesmente não precisa ter o método na filha. Se realmente precisa ter este método para fazer outras coisas nele, aí você deveria declarar o método na `Pai` como `virtual`. Fora isto não vejo alternativas e nem sei se precisa haver.

Comment: Entendi. O problema é ter que ficar declarando o método na classe filha então? O trabalho excessivo? Eu tenho a impressão que este problema é de difícil solução se houver alguma. Ou seja, provavelmente é mais fácil fazer essa gambiarra mesmo. Pensei em métodos de extensão mas teria a limitação deles só poderem acessar membros públicos.

Comment: Sim a razão é o trabalho. Este situação surgiu já há bastante tempo. Tentei várias coisas e acabei por desistir. Foi a pergunta sobre [interfaces](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47925/2541) que me relembrou esta questão. Note que a nível de interfaces isto resolve-se utilizando mais um tipo genérico *TOut*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vou responder que que não sei se resolve o problema mas pelo menos ajuda ter ideias:

```
using System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var pai = new Pai();
        WriteLine(pai.Metodo1(1).GetType());
        var filha = new Filha();
        WriteLine(filha.Metodo1(1).GetType());
        filha.PropriedadeB = "xxx";
        WriteLine(filha.Metodo1(1).GetType());
        var temp = filha.Metodo1(1);
        WriteLine(temp.PropriedadeB);
    }
}

public class Pai : Pai<Pai> { }

public class Pai<T> where T : Pai<T> {
    protected string PropriedadeA { get; set; }
    public T Metodo1(int valor) {
        //Vários procedimentos feitos aqui
        PropriedadeA = "Resultado do tratamento";
        return (T)this;
    }
}

public class Filha : Pai<Filha> {
    public string PropriedadeB { get; set; }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/0GNQlX). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ilVnqc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/InheritanceThis.cs).

Certamente tem limitações mas já resolve alguma coisa.

Mas se prepare também para ter que ter o trabalho de ficar reproduzindo métodos desnecessariamente. Às vezes para simplificar a vida do consumidor aumenta bastante o trabalho do fornecedor.

Em C# 9 é possível usar o `return` covariante, então é possível reescrever o método mas retornando `Filha` em vez de `Pai` mantendo a sobrescrita sem usar o `new`. Não estou dizendo que é o que deseja, mas é uma outra forma para alguns cenários.

Comment: Isso foi a primeira coisa que tentei mas, ao fazer `return (T)this;`, recebia a mensagem *"Cannot cast expression of type Pai<T> to T"*. Nunca me ocorreu em usar a cláusula ***where*** que, evidentemente, resolveria o problema.

Comment: QUando eu estava resolvendo [esse problema](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/47929/101) eu tive que fazer isto para compilar, aí você deu sorte e deu p/ aplicar a mesma solução. Aqui a "gambiarra" teve que ser maior.

Comment: A "gambiarra" irá evitar ter de escrever muitas linhas de código. A declaração da classe é que ficará um pouco extensa mas, como são internas, o consumidor não terá de as instanciar.

Comment: Sim, por isso coloquei entre aspas, é algo que é útil, mas fica bem esquisito.

Comment: Apenas agora, que tive que instanciar a classe é que vi o verdadeiro segredo da solução. Não me tinha apercebido disto: `public class Pai : Pai<Pai> { }`. Agora percebo quando você diz *"fica bem esquisito"*

Comment: É o único que conseguir instanciar a classe declarada desta desta forma. For for instanciar direto a classe genérica, vai ter que colocar o tipo na instanciação. Mas qual é o tipo? `Pai`? Ele não existe, só existe, o `Pai<T>`. Ou seja, teria uma recursão infinita. Por sorte tem solução.

Comment: *"teria uma recursão infinita."* Foi essa a conclusão que eu cheguei quando quis instanciar a classe. Então voltei aqui para perceber o que faltava. Obrigado!

Comment: @ramaral, caso não tenha reparado, repare que há uma diferença hierárquica importante entre este código e o seu original. No seu, Filha herda de Pai. Neste aqui, Pai e Filha não estão na mesma linha hierárquica - ao invés, ambos herdam de Pai<T>, que é uma terceira classe. Ou seja, o que você tem aqui é "**pai é irmão da filha**", e não um relacionamento de pai e filha de fato.

Comment: Sim. Mas em termos práticos, e é o que eu pretendia, Filha herda de Pai<T>, que é onde está o código a ser reaproveitado. Pai só existe para ser possível criar instâncias em que o tipo genérico é a própria classe.

Answer (score 1):

[Fiz o seguinte teste](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GejbRB):

```
using System;

public class Pai
{
    protected string PropriedadeA { get; set; }
    public Pai Metodo1(int valor)
    {
        //Vários procedimentos feitos aqui
        PropriedadeA = "Resultado do tratamento";
        return this;
    }
}

public class Filha : Pai
{

}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        var filha = new Filha().Metodo1(1);
        Console.WriteLine(filha.GetType());
    }
}
```

O tipo devolvido foi `Filha`. Não é preciso reintroduzir o método.

Comment: Estava testando e cheguei no mesmo resultado. A não ser que ele queira fazer algo extra no método da filha e por isto precise definir novamente o método, aí acho que só com `virtual` mesmo.

Comment: @bigown O problema é que não consigo aceder a métodos/propriedades declarados na classe filha sem usar cast

Comment: @ramaral coloque em exemplo mais completo que dê para ver esse problema acontecendo. Acabei de testar com `virtual` e ajudou entender um pouco o problema. Não funciona, porque como está retornando `this` os tipos de retorno do método da `Pai` e da `Filha` são distintos. Nunca tinha visto um caso assim e nunca tinha pensado nisto. De qualquer forma, o `new` está resolvendo o problema e você quer uma alternativa ou nem funciona? https://dotnetfiddle.net/Tt3icP

Comment: @bigown Adicionei à pergunta a razão dessa necessidade.

Comment: Neste caso acho que seria pertinente uma pergunta detalhando melhor essa necessidade de acesso, envolvendo um exemplo mais concreto.