# Qual a real utilidade de Interface em PHP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, característica-linguagem, interface

Eu sei q a `interface` é utilizada como um padrão comum. Porém não me parece ser útil. Pois do que adianta criar uma interface que sé tem o nome dos métodos?

Eu tenho que codificar cada um deles na classe que está implementando a interface. Qual o ganho?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em PHP? Realmente não tem muita vantagem, mas está mudando com a metamorfose da linguagem.

Se você for programar como PHP foi concebido realmente não faz sentido porque interface é um mecanismo de contrato onde você diz que métodos um tipo de ter e aí você cria tipos que se conformam com ela, e no seu código pode dizer que algum lugar aceita uma interface e aí qualquer objeto que implemente a interface poderá ser usado ali porque ele atende ao requisito dela.

É uma forma de você dar um nome para uma operação que um objeto pode fazer, e depois pode dizer que aceita objetos que sabem fazer a operação. Então é um mecanismo para garantir robustez, dar segurança de tipo.

Porém PHP é uma linguagem de tipagem dinâmica, e não faz sentido pedir segurança de tipo em uma linguagem assim. PHP é uma linguagem de *script* e não deveria ter que lidar com este tipo de complexidade.

É verdade que PHP percebeu que isso não é muito bom e está mudando a filosofia, mas não dá para arrumar tudo por questões de compatibilidade, então fica uma coisa híbrida e tem o pior dos dois mundos (parte do melhor também, claro, mas parcial não ajuda tanto assim).

Quer segurança de tipos? Ótimo, use em uma linguagem de tipagem estática que obriga isso ocorrer em todos os casos. Gosta de PHP? Use [Hack](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143708/101). Senão pense em Java, C#, essas coisas.

Não se importa com segurança de tipos? Ok, se realmente o que faz é *script* ela não é tão necessária, mas aí fica estranho usar interface.

Se você entender tudo o que está fazendo no código verá que boa parte do que se prega hoje em PHP não faz sentido. As pessoas usam sem questionar. Que bom que questionou.

Veja mais em:

- [Diferença entre classe e interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136404/101)
- [Como e quando usar Interface?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107524/101)
- [Interface ou Abstract?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35317/101)
- [Programar voltado para interface e não para a implementação, por quê?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101)
- [Devo utilizar classe abstrata ou interface?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166530/101)
- [Implementar Interfaces](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47925/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Maravilha ! Ótima resposta... eh exatamente oq penso. Abraço

Answer (score -4):

Eu pensava da mesma forma, mas a interface evita a repetição de código quando você tem comportamentos diferentes dos mesmos tipos de objeto.

Imagina que você está usando o banco de dados Mysql e você possue uma classe Connection . Essa classe faz uma conexão direta com Mysql.

Agora imagina que em toda sua camada de persistência tenha a classe Connection e chegou um cliente novo a qual será preciso ter um novo banco de dados e você agora ira usar dois bancos de dados.

Então você precisa mudar seu código dando suporte ao novo banco e garantindo o suporte ao banco anterior. Ou seja em alguns lugares será a Connection do Mysql e em outros da Connection de um novo banco.

Para evitar duas Connections fazendo a mesma coisa, você cria uma interface Connection e as Classes ConnectionMysql e ConnectionPostgree irão implementar ela.

Agora seu código pode usar a interface Connection invés das classes ConnectionMysql ou ConnectionPostgree.

Comment: Mas entao nao eh desnecessario isso ??  ppis do q adianta implementar as duas classe com a interface da conexao se eu terei q editar cada classe individualmente e configurar o metodo q foi nomeado na interface ? Isso q nao consigo entender, dá na mesma ja q vou ter q ajustar a classe parara a conexao e nao a interface. Num concorda ??

Comment: Você usuaria uma interface com apenas um método. GetConnection, e cada classe implementaria esse método. Uso de interfaces faz parte do conceito SOLID e é amplamente utilizado em frameworks.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID